# SQL Left Join & Right Join - which table is left or right?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join

I search left join and right join in sql. And the explanations says that the left join starts selecting data from the left table. It compares values in the x column with the values in the y column in the right table. There are 2 queries used left/ight join below.

Which company produced this product? ( query 1)

If we want to answer of this query with left join.Then the left table is Products and right table is Companies.

What products did this company produce? (query 2)

If we want to answer of this query with right join.Then the left table is Companies and right table is Products.

I interpreted the queries as above.I'm not sure if it's true or not.
There is a "Product" table and this table inclueds "Pname", "Product_no", "Cname", "Company_no" columns.

```
Query 1
SELECT P."Pname" AS "Product_name",
       C."Cname" AS "Company_name"
FROM "Products" AS P 
LEFT JOIN "Products" AS C
ON P."Company_no" = C."Product_no"

Query 2
SELECT C."Cname" AS "Company_name",
       P."Pname" AS "Product_name"         
FROM "Products" AS P 
RIGHT JOIN "Products" AS C
ON P."Company_no" = C."Product_no"
```

My questions are:

1. How do we determine which of the two tables is the left table or the right table?
2. How do we determine which is the left table or the right table when doing left join/right join on the same table? (self join-- IN QUERY 1 AND QUERY 2)
3. What is the exact difference between left join and right join?

Thank you...

Comment: Note that a "table" in SQL is not necessarily a `TABLE` in your DBMS: a `VIEW` is a table, a CTE is a table, and subqueries in the  `FROM` clause are also all tables as far as SQL is concerned - so a self-join is not exactly what you think it is.

Comment: @Dai Thank you for explanation. I am new in DBMS.Could you give more information about this sentence " subqueries in the FROM clause are also all tables as far as SQL is concerned " ?

Answer (score 3):

"Left" and "Right" basically mean "first" and "second" here: imagine writing your SQL query all on one line, the first table you mention will be on the left, the next one to its right. A left join says the table on the left is mandatory and the one on the right optional, a right join says the opposite.

The order doesn't actually make a difference to the end result: any query that can be written with a right join can be written with a left join instead just by mentioning the tables in a different order (there may be exceptions, but I've never come across one).

In practice, you'll pretty much always use a left join, because it's generally easier to follow if you put the mandatory tables first, then the optional ones.

Finally, your example doesn't make much sense: `P."Company_no" = C."Product_no"` would be matching on things that don't relate to each other. The main time you'd join a table to itself is if you had a "parent-child" relationship, like "OwnedByCompanyNo". You might then have a left join where the left (mandatory) table is all companies in a particular town, and the right (optional) table is the company that owns them, if there is one. Again, flipping this to a right join would just be a case of mentioning the tables in the other order.

Answer (score 0):

1. The table you define your "join on" is your right table.

LEFT JOIN "Products" AS
C ON P."Company_no" = C."Product_no"

The important stuff is: "C ON P"
The left side is C, the right side is P

2. The Difference is.. Let's watch on these comparison:

Left Join: C ON P (C Joins on P)
Is the same as
Right Join: P ON C (C Joins on P)

The difference is the direction of the JOIN.

Maybe this helps you:
https://www.dofactory.com/img/sql/sql-joins.png